# Groovy script from docker container

Tags: curl, docker, groovy

I'm trying to get the html response from my web page using **docker** and **groovy** script. Normally I could use **curl** as below:

```
curl 10.1.1.167:1410
```

...and get the response "OK"

But when I'm trying to get the same with starting docker and groovy:

```
[mycomp@my-host script] cat run.sh
#!/bin/bash
docker run                                                          \
    --rm                                                            \
    -e TZ=Europe/Warsaw                                             \
    -v /home/user1/monitoring/:/home/user1/monitoring/:Z      \
    -w /home/user1/monitoring/script                             \
    --name groovy2 groovy:2.4.11-jdk8                               \
    groovy run.groovy

[mycomp@my-host script] cat run.groovy
def server = "10.1.1.167"
println "http://$server:1410/".toURL().text
```

... I'm getting such an Timeout error (after many seconds...):

```
[mycomp@my-host script] ./run.sh
Caught: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at run.run(run.groovy:2)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe you can tell me? Maybe you can propose my something other solution (but still using docker and groovy)

---

EDIT:
Program is ok, I had a problem with connection to this ip address.

Comment: What is your base image?

Comment: @Rao: groovy:2.4.11-jdk8

Comment: I guess it might related to network configuration. More or less you need to add you docker container to local network. It also shouldn't work with curl.

Comment: What is this IP for 10.1.1.167? what is the network infra?

Comment: What is the output of command on host machine | docker container ? - `telnet 10.1.1.167 1410`?

Comment: Thanks you all for suggestion about infrastructure and telnet'ing this addres. Of course I had an limitiation of network connection. I added some rule and now everything is ok.